# Anaconda with spyder: ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkConf'

Tags: python, pyspark, anaconda, spyder

I have `pyspark` installed on testenv in anaconda (by using: `conda install -c conda-forge pyspark`), it's here (I think)

`/Users/myuser/anaconda3/envs/testenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark`

This path exists, next I start `spyder`:

`(testenv1) ➜  ~ spyder`

And this code yields the below error, I thought that `site-packeges` are automatically "included", or is it a different problem?

```
import os
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = "/Users/myuser/anaconda3/envs/testenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark" # Not working but also not sure why I need to add this line at all pyspark appears to be in `site-packages`

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("WordCount")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
```

And I get the below error:

```
runfile('/Users/myuser/dev/projects/python-snippets/pyspark.py', wdir='/Users/myuser/dev/projects/python-snippets')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-969f4e596614>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/myuser/dev/projects/python-snippets/pyspark.py', wdir='/Users/myuser/dev/projects/python-snippets')

  File "/Users/myuser/anaconda3/envs/testenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/myuser/anaconda3/envs/testenv1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/myuser/dev/projects/python-snippets/pyspark.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

  File "/Users/myuser/dev/projects/python-snippets/pyspark.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

ImportError: cannot import name 'SparkConf'
```

Note that I have tried updating the python interpreter in spyder to: `/Users/myuser/anaconda3/envs/testenv1/bin/python3.6` but I get the same exact error.

Comment: Is `python-snippets/pyspark.py` is your file? If yes the you should not use the name `pyspark.py` as it will conflict with the original `pyspark` package. Please rename the file to something else and try again

Comment: @TarunLalwani that was it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `python-snippets/pyspark.py` your file? If yes the you should not use the name `pyspark.py` as it will conflict with the original `pyspark` package.

Please rename the file to something else and it should work